# Python3 Windows multiprocessing passing socket to process

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, sockets, multiprocessing

I'm trying to make multiprocessing `ServerApp` to work on Windows. I guess the issue is missing `os.fork()` feature so I'll have to pass `socket` somehow which is not pickleable (?!).

I've seen that this might be possible using `reduce_handle` and `rebuild_handle` from `multiprocessing.reduction` as shown [here](https://gist.github.com/sunilmallya/4662837) but those methods are not available in Python 3 (?!). Although I have available `duplicate` and `steal_handle` available I can't find an example how to use them or whether I need them at all.

Also, I'd like to know if `logging` is going to be the problem when creating a new process?

Here's my ServerApp sample:

```
import logging
import socket

from select import select
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import Queue
from multiprocessing import Process
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep


class ServerApp(object):

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)


    def conn_handler(self, connection, address, buffer):

        self.logger.info("[%d] - Connection from %s:%d", self.id, address[0], address[1])

        try:
            while True:

                command = None
                received_data = b''
                readable, writable, exceptional = select([connection], [], [], 0)  # Check for client commands

                if readable:
                    # Get Command  ... There is more code here
                    command = 'Something'


                if command == 'Something':
                    connection.sendall(command_response)
                else:
                    print(':(')

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            connection.close()
            self.client_buffers.remove(buffer)
            self.logger.info("[%d] - Connection from %s:%d has been closed.", self.id, address[0], address[1])


    def join(self):

        while self.listener.is_alive():
            self.listener.join(0.5)


    def acceptor(self):

        while True:
            self.logger.info("[%d] - Waiting for connection on %s:%d", self.id, self.ip, self.port)

            # Accept a connection on the bound socket and fork a child process to handle it.
            conn, address = self.socket.accept()

            # Create Queue which will represent buffer for specific client and add it o list of all client buffers
            buffer = Queue()
            self.client_buffers.append(buffer)

            process = Process(target=self.conn_handler, args=(conn, address, buffer))
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()
            self.clients.append(process)

            # Close the connection fd in the parent, since the child process has its own reference.
            conn.close()


    def __init__(self, id, port=4545, ip='127.0.0.1', method='tcp', buffer_size=2048):

        self.id = id
        self.port = port
        self.ip = ip

        self.socket = None
        self.listener = None
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size

        # Additional attributes here....

        self.clients = []
        self.client_buffers = []


    def run(self):

        # Create TCP socket, bind port and listen for incoming connections
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.socket.listen(5)

        self.listener = Thread(target=self.acceptor)  # Run acceptor thread to handle new connection
        self.listener.daemon = True
        self.listener.start()
```

Comment: You writing some code but can't see any `protocol` definitions. Can't define any accepting rule  if already accepted(what is filter ?).

Comment: @dsgdfg Not sure if I got you correct but each connection should be accepted and handled by the separate process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To allow connection pickling (including sockets) for python3, you should use the `mulitprocessing.allow_connection_pickling`. It registers reducers for sockets in `ForkingPickler`. For instance:

```
import socket
import multiprocessing as mp
mp.allow_connection_pickling()


def _test_connection(conn):
    msg = conn.recv(2)
    conn.send(msg)
    conn.close()
    print("ok")

if __name__ == '__main__':
    server, client = socket.socketpair()

    p = mp.Process(target=_test_connection, args=(server,))
    p.start()

    client.settimeout(5)

    msg = b'42'
    client.send(msg)
    assert client.recv(2) == msg

    p.join()
    assert p.exitcode == 0

    client.close()
    server.close()
```

I also noticed that you have some other issues unrealted to the pickling of `socket`.

- When use `self.conn_handler` as a target, the multiprocessing will try to pickle the entire object `self`. This is an issue as your object contains some `Thread` that cannot be pickled. You should thus remove `self` from the closure of your target function. It can be done by using the `@staticmethod` decorator and by removing all mention of `self` in the function.
- Also, the `logging` module is not done to handle multiple processes. Basically, all the logs from the launched `Process` will be lost with your current code. To fix that, you can either start a new `logging` once you start the second `Process` (at the beginning of `conn_handler`) or use the `multiprocessing` logging utility.

This can gives something like this:

```
import logging
import socket

from select import select
from threading import Thread
from multiprocessing import util, get_context
from sys import stdout
from time import sleep

util.log_to_stderr(20)
ctx = get_context("spawn")


class ServerApp(object):

    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    handler = logging.StreamHandler(stdout)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s')
    handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    logger.addHandler(handler)

    def __init__(self, id, port=4545, ip='127.0.0.1', method='tcp',
                buffer_size=2048):

        self.id = id
        self.port = port
        self.ip = ip

        self.socket = None
        self.listener = None
        self.buffer_size = buffer_size

        # Additional attributes here....

        self.clients = []
        self.client_buffers = []

    @staticmethod
    def conn_handler(id, connection, address, buffer):

        print("test")
        util.info("[%d] - Connection from %s:%d", id, address[0], address[1])

        try:
            while True:

                command = None
                received_data = b''
                # Check for client commands
                readable, writable, exceptional = select([connection], [], [],
                                                        0)

                if readable:
                    # Get Command  ... There is more code here
                    command = 'Something'

                if command == 'Something':
                    connection.sendall(b"Coucouc")
                    break
                else:
                    print(':(')
                sleep(.1)

        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        finally:
            connection.close()
            util.info("[%d] - Connection from %s:%d has been closed.", id,
                    address[0], address[1])
            print("Close")

    def join(self):

        while self.listener.is_alive():
            self.listener.join(0.5)

    def acceptor(self):

        while True:
            self.logger.info("[%d] - Waiting for connection on %s:%d", self.id,
                            self.ip, self.port)

            # Accept a connection on the bound socket and fork a child process
            # to handle it.
            conn, address = self.socket.accept()

            # Create Queue which will represent buffer for specific client and
            # add it o list of all client buffers
            buffer = ctx.Queue()
            self.client_buffers.append(buffer)

            process = ctx.Process(target=self.conn_handler,
                                args=(self.id, conn, address, buffer))
            process.daemon = True
            process.start()
            self.clients.append(process)

            # Close the connection fd in the parent, since the child process
            # has its own reference.
            conn.close()

    def run(self):

        # Create TCP socket, bind port and listen for incoming connections
        self.socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.socket.bind((self.ip, self.port))
        self.socket.listen(5)

        # Run acceptor thread to handle new connection
        self.listener = Thread(target=self.acceptor)
        self.listener.daemon = True
        self.listener.start()

        self.listener.join()


def main():
    app = ServerApp(0)
    app.run()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I only tested it on Unix and python3.6 but it should not have behavior too different as I use the spawn context`, which should behave like the`Process` in windows.

Comment: Sorry about the delay. I've tested the `allow_connection_pickling` but it has no effect. However, I've noticed that I'm getting two different errors (running the same code twice). Here's the [first one](http://pastebin.com/zyS2Sbtm) and here's the [second one](http://pastebin.com/7FQ1nvxN).  When I don't assign listener as ServerApp property (just `listener` instead of `self.listener`) I don't have the error but also the handler process is never executed.

Comment: This is not an issue with `socket` pickling. If you read the errors, it fails to pickle a `_thread.Lock` and some `io` objects. I would say that this is related to the pickling of the whole `ServerApp` object, needed as you use a instance method to start your new `Process`. You should either use a `@staticmethod` decorator for `conn_handler` or remove it from the class. This is also a good practice as it is not safe to pickle the whole object (for instance if it handles some password). Also, try to provide some basic script reproducing your error to allow testing.

Comment: Also, as a good practive, you should use the `multiprocessing.utils.log_to_stderr` and `multiprocessing.utils.debug/info` to get a consistent logging accross your `Process`. If you need to use custom logging, you should start it at the beginning of your target function as `logging` is only designed to work with one `Process`.

Comment: Thanks! I've managed to make it run just by removing `listener` as part of the object. Please check this [commit](https://github.com/iicsys/pypmu/commit/ce968de8052ce95daa05f3b37acffee078db422c). This part `if __name__ == '__main__':` also caused me troubles. Now it's working for one client (run tinyPDC as a client) but as soon as I run another instance of tinyPDC  I get this [error](http://pastebin.com/GjiGG040). Not sure if can be reproduced on Unix, since it's working for me.

Comment: It looks like that Python is handling most of the pickling on it's own. I'll try to now to make `handler` as static method.

Comment: Have you seen the edited answer? Is the code working?

Comment: Sorry for keeping you waiting. Yes! I've managed to get it work using `@staticmethod`. Thanks!