# Sending socket through multiprocessing Queue Python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, multiprocessing

I am trying to implement a generic "timeout" function which allows me to send a function to be run, and if it doesn't complete after a certain amount of time, kill it. Here is the current implementation:

```
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue
import multiprocessing as mp
mp.allow_connection_pickling()
from fn.monad import Full, Empty
import traceback


def timeout(timeout, func, args=()):
    '''
    Calls function, and if it times out returns an Empty()
    :param timeout: int | The amount of time to wait for the function
    :param func: () => Any | The function to call (must take no arguments)
    :param queue: Queue | The multiprocessing queue to put the result into
    :return Option | Full(Result) if we get the result, Empty() if it times out
    '''


    queue = Queue()
    p = Process(target=_helper_func, args=(func, queue, args,))
    p.daemon = True
    p.start()
    p.join(timeout)
    if p.is_alive() or queue.empty():
        p.terminate()
        return Empty()
    else:
        out = queue.get()
        # if 'rebuild_handle' in dir(out):
        #   out.rebuild_handle()
        return Full(out)

def _helper_func(func, queue, args):
    try:
        func(*args, queue)
    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

The function must put the "return value" into the multiprocessing queue. However, when timeout is run, and a socket is put into the queue, I get the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "socket_test.py", line 27, in <module>
    print(q.get())
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/queues.py", line 113, in get
    return _ForkingPickler.loads(res)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 239, in _rebuild_socket
    fd = df.detach()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 57, in detach
    with _resource_sharer.get_connection(self._id) as conn:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/resource_sharer.py", line 87, in get_connection
    c = Client(address, authkey=process.current_process().authkey)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 487, in Client
    c = SocketClient(address)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 614, in SocketClient
    s.connect(address)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

I have tried various previous stack overflow posts, such as the following: [Python3 Windows multiprocessing passing socket to process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42367770/python3-windows-multiprocessing-passing-socket-to-process)

Please let me know if you know of a solution to this issue, as it is throwing a giant wrench into my code. Thanks!

Comment: 'Connection refused' means nothing was listening at the IP:port you tried to connect to. It doesn't have anything to do with your queue. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: This is after a successful connection. No matter what if you pass a socket to another process you get an error like this. See the linked thread above.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your helper `Process` is exiting before the other has a chance to retrieve the object from the `Queue`.  You can add a short `sleep()` before exiting if you're expecting the object to be read out of the `Queue` relatively quickly or have a separate `Queue` to send a message back to the `Process` indicating the object has been received and it's safe to exit.

See [this](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/issues/7181#issuecomment-434427480) pytorch issue for an example implementation.